# Google reports that robots.txt is blocking site - but I don't think it is

Tags: google-search-console, robots.txt, xml-sitemap

I have a site map at `http://www.example.com/sitemap_index.xml` that has been sumbitted to Google Webmaster Tools, however... Google is reporting that my sitemap is being blocked by robots.txt.

My robots.txt looks like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /oldsite/
```

I have checked this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060245/why-is-google-webmaster-tools-completely-misreading-my-robots-txt-file) and several others but it doesn't answer my question. When I go to crawl errors it says 'no data yet, check back later'

Why is Google Webmaster Tools reporting this issue? is this something that will just sort itself. I have only just submitted the site to Google and I am a little bit nervous - itchy client...

Comment: Your robots.txt is fine, it is not certainly blocking your sitemap_index.xml, just give it a time, GWT do not respond in real-time.

Comment: How long has it said that? It may not update for a couple of days.

Comment: Can take more than a couple of days, can take a week or two, depends on how important Google thinks the site is.

Comment: Have you ever had a different robots.txt file that did perhaps block this? (Whilst developing the site perhaps?) Is this the _only_ sitemap you have submitted?